# yq - Find and replace map value by map key

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, yq

I have a yml file called `output.yml` which contains a K8s Service, Deployment and Ingress resources like so (lots of fields omitted for brevity):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-name
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: instance-name
spec:
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-name
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: instance-name
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-name
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: instance-name
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: app-name
      app.kubernetes.io/instance: instance-name
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: app-name
        app.kubernetes.io/instance: instance-name
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: app-name
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: instance-name
```

What I would like to do is, for all occurrences of where the key = `app.kubernetes.io/instance`, replace all values of `instance-name` with a different value say `app-instance-name2`. I have tried several things like using the `select` and `has` operators like so: `yq eval '(.. | select(has("app.kubernetes.io/instance"))'` but it returns all map keys instead of just the one I want to update and then I'm not really sure where to go from there.

At the moment, I am just updating each individual value like so:

```
yq e '.metadata.labels["app.kubernetes.io/instance"] = strenv(INSTANCE_NAME)' -i output.yml
yq e 'select(.kind == "Service").spec.selector["app.kubernetes.io/instance"] = strenv(INSTANCE_NAME)' -i output.yml
yq e 'select(.kind == "Deployment").spec.selector.matchLabels["app.kubernetes.io/instance"] = strenv(INSTANCE_NAME)' -i output.yml
yq e 'select(.kind == "Deployment").spec.template.metadata.labels["app.kubernetes.io/instance"] = strenv(INSTANCE_NAME)' -i output.yml
```

which works but is pretty verbose so I'd like if there was a succinct single line option?

I am using yq version 4.17.2 from https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq

Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be accomplished by doing a [recursive decent](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/recursive-descent-glob#recursively-find-nodes-with-keys) to identify keys matching your string and update their value part using `|=`

```
yq e '(..|select(has("app.kubernetes.io/instance")).["app.kubernetes.io/instance"]) |= "app-instance-name2"' output.yml
```

Starting [v4.18.1](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/releases/tag/v4.18.1), the `eval` flag is the default action, so the `e` flag can be avoided